# How do I query parse.com for a list of my registers apps and their associated client IDs?

Tags: xcode, macos, parse-platform

I am a relatively new Parse.Com user.  All of the examples involve using the credentials of one of your apps to interact with Parse.  I am writing an OSX application to use as sort of a console, and I need to query Parse.Com for a list of all of my registered apps along with their Client IDs so that my console can then interact with Parse on an individual app level.

Comment: There is no public API for that AFAIK. It should be possible, but you'd have to reverse engineer the process that a browser based user goes through - as in logging in, then performing the same set of javascript calls, and parsing the HTML returned that a browser performs. Good luck with that. It'll be super-brittle.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a master Parse table that has a list of all of your apps with their client IDs and any other info you may need.  Then you just need to query that one table to get the rest of the data.  This can then be modified on the server.